# What is this “ɹɐʍɯɐq” nonsense?

Tags: discussion, spam

<sup>**EDIT**: Rewrote offending word in upsidedownascript so as not to provide free advertising for the spamvertiser.</sup>

I may be seeing this only today. Maybe it's been going on since a long time but the only post I could find about it is from 9 hours earlier.

There isn't any post about this on the main meta, too. Is someone targeting english SE? Can we completely block posts containing the `ɹɐʍɯɐq` word?

Comment: It's spam. Please do flag as spam (and NOT vote to close, and NOT vote down as well as flag).

Comment: I'm doing exactly as you described but it's extremely annoying.

Comment: Tedious. But it's the only way to persuade the spammers that ELU is not a good target.

Comment: I'm flagging as spam, but I'm using up all my flags :( .  Also: why not also downvote?  (And is this spammer targeting *only* EL&U, or are other stacks also being effected?)

Comment: @DanBron downvoting reduces the chances that other users will see the question. The question needs to be seen by enough users who can flag it as spam; enough flags will cause it to be deleted.

Comment: Are they abusing automated signup or what? New users each time